# Fatal signal 11 (andengine project)

Tags: java, android, mobile, box2d, andengine

I'm creating and android game powered by andengine framework the box2d extension
I'm getting "Fatal Signal 11" which seems to happen out of nowhere (I guess you can call it randomly)

there no clues (at least, I don't aware to any clues to help me solve this problem)

my guesses are:
1) I'm creating game's entities using TimerTask class
2) maybe it has something to do with concurrency?

what do you think?
thanks,
socksocket

[image]

Comment: I especially like that hex memory address of 0xdeadbaad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could still use a TimerTask, you just need to be sure to call anything relating to AndEngine (creating or deleting sprites, etc) on the AndEngine update thread - you can use

```
runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
// do your stuff in here
}
});
```

Comment: OK. I need to look over all my code  
but I am pretty much certain that this is the problem  

thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed it by taking the TimerTask out of the equation.

Comment: I made some changes. I think it helped

Comment: What were they? I've been fiddling around and I cant work out how to get the same effect as a TimerTask without implementing it back in.

Answer (score 1):

it says touchEvent...maybe you set your density value of your FixtureDef too high....
try to set the density value <=1000 like below:

FixtureDef wallFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1000, 0.0f, 1.0f);

Body mGoundBody=PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, ground, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);

hope this information can help you...