# AndEngine: Getting a SIGSEGV and TouchEventPool Events

Tags: android, andengine

I'm developing a game with android using andengine. Basically, I'm using 2 `ArrayList` to store my 2 types of Sprites. I'm adding and removing both types of `Sprite` at runtime, in reaction to user interaction. However, I'll get random crashes with only the following error codes:

```
10-09 12:11:13.532: A/libc(8015): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1)
10-09 12:11:13.572: V/AndEngine(8015): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 2 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-09 12:11:13.572: V/AndEngine(8015): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 2 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-09 12:11:13.602: V/AndEngine(8015): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 3 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-09 12:11:13.602: V/AndEngine(8015): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 3 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-09 12:11:13.622: V/AndEngine(8015): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 4 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-09 12:11:13.622: V/AndEngine(8015): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 4 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-09 12:11:16.195: V/AndEngine(8015): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 5 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-09 12:11:16.195: V/AndEngine(8015): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 5 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-09 12:11:16.275: V/AndEngine(8015): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 6 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-09 12:11:16.275: V/AndEngine(8015): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 6 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
```

As I continue to move my finger on the screen, the `TouchEvent` pool warnings continue popping up, but the game itself is hung. I honestly have no idea what is causing this! I've done a lot of looking around, and can't even pinpoint the crash on a single action.

My method of creating/removing my Sprites is as follows:

**TypeASprite**:

- create inside a `TimerHandler`
- remove inside `ContactListener` spawning a `runOnUpdateThread()` `Runnable`

**TypeBSprite**:

- create inside a overriden `onSceneTouchEvent()`, since the Activity extends an `IOnSceneTouchListener`.
- remove inside `ContactListener` spawning a `runOnUpdateThread()` `Runnable`

Each time a `Sprite` is created, it's added to its respective `ArrayList`. When it needs to be removed, it's removed from the `ArrayList` through the `ContactListener`.

Any help/ideas would be really appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT: Through some trial and error, I'm ***pretty*** sure the issue is with the TypeBSprite

EDIT: I've implemented my TypeBSprite creation like this:

```
mEngine.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        AnimatedSprite sprite = new AnimatedSprite(sX, sY, mSpriteRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());

        sprite.setRotation(sRotation);
        mScene.attachChild(sprite);

        Body body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(mPhysicsWorld, sprite, BodyType.StaticBody, MY_FIXTURE);
        sprite.setUserData("spiteB");
        body.setUserData(sprite);
        mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(sprite, body, true, true)); 
    }
});
```

Comment: 0xdeadbaad, funny. Try searching for that address on Google, some of the results seem promising, especially http://stackoverflow.com/a/11617921/1084813 and http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/fatal-signal-11-what-to-do-t8523.html

Comment: thanks, took a look at those. I updated with some of my findings

Comment: You should add the TypeBSprite inside Runnable on Update Thread. The Box2D engine doesn't like having he scene changed from elsewhere. (You are using Box2D, right? I concluded you do based on the segfault)

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Box2D extension for AndEngine. I updated with my changed code, but the problem persists. Is there another way to create the Runnable?

Comment: Creating the Runnable differently should not have any effect on the problem, this is probably not a Java issue. One thing that caught my eye is the fixture, which, if you adhere to the standard naming conventions, is a constant. I have no idea what the implications of this are, but try creating a new one for each Body.

Comment: I made the FixtureDef create itself for each Sprite, but that doesn't seem to be doing it. I feel like it might lie within the IOnSceneTouchListener, because EVERY time this error occurs, I'm bombarded with the TouchEvent pool warnings, which continue to appear when I touch the screen even after the SEGV error. Still working on it, and I'll update if I get any breakthroughs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out! The problem lies in the time gap between registering an `runOnUpdateThread` `Runnable` and the actual execution of it. The problem was that the `ContactListener` was being called multiple times for the same collision, and thus the `runOnUpdateThread` being used to delete the bodies was being called multiple times on the same object.

To fix it, I made the `ContactListener` set the `UserData` of the Sprite to "deleted". When the `ContactListener` was called again on the same object, the "`if (...)` statements comparing `Sprite`'s `UserData` would ignore it, since it should be on the road to deletion already.

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Main reason of error Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x28ac9648 (code=1)
is due to stack is full you need to clear stack on runtime or recycle

look in log cat you are allocating  items but not recycling

its also giving error  with 6 item not yet recycled

thus if u keep on recycling older items you wll find game
working fine without any error