# Not using any native code but getting SIGSEGV error?

Tags: android, andengine, segmentation-fault

I am developing a simple game with using Andengine.Desperately I am getting `Fatal signal 11 SIGSEGV 0xdeadbaad code=1` error in my game randomly.

I searched almost every topic about this error and I read that this is a segmentation error and caused by the NDK.But I am NOT using any native code. Actually,I implemented Android NDK to Eclipse but not using any C/C++ code in my game.

I cannot put a log because it is just saying `Fatal signal 11 SIGSEGV 0xdeadbaad code=1`.I am not putting my whole code too as it may be too long but if you want I can put it.

Just asking that if I remove NDK,may this error be dissappear? Or what else can make this error occure and how to handle it?

I am sorry if I had a mistake.Thank you.

Edit: I have a body removal part in my game and may be this part is the source of problem?

Here what I do:

```
scene.detachChildren();
scene.clearEntityModifiers();
scene.clearTouchAreas();
scene.clearUpdateHandlers();

physicsWorld.unregisterPhysicsConnector(physicsWorld.getPhysicsConnectorManager().findPhysicsConnectorByShape(spriteHero));
physicsWorld.destroyBody(bodyHero);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=0xdeadbaad+andengine

Comment: thank you for your comment but I have looked that topics before.

Comment: are you doing the body removal code on the UpdateThread? try sticking it in a runOnUpdateThread block and see

Comment: I tried it and now I am getting 'Fatal signal 11 SIGSEGV 0x00000155 code=1'

Comment: ok, sorry - I'm out of ideas - the last time I saw this was in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614786/fatal-signal-11-andengine-project/ and that helped in that case.

Comment: 0xdeadbaad is a libc abort().  One common cause is native heap corruption.  Do you see any errors in the logcat output above the fatal signal line?  What does the stacktrace in the native crash in logcat look like?

Comment: I have suffered with this at times too! Echoing jmr499485, furthermore I would make sure that anything which removes children from a scene or changes their properties in any way is also inside the runOnUpdateThread unless you are doing so from an IUpdateHandler. This includes any interrupts such as calls to touch event interfaces, modifier listeners e.t.c. When changing a scene my SceneManager always calls the unload method in the current scene before switching in which all update handlers, touch event handlers, sprites, bodies are removed. This is all done in a runOnUpdateThread.

Comment: Neglected to include ContactListeners also.

Comment: you say, you don't use native code - but the andengine box2d-extension makes use of a binary library and has a wrapper around it.

Comment: addition: 
i suggest your body or the already detached spriteHero is null. and you don't need to `unRegisterPhysicsConnector`, that will be done inside the `destroyBody` afaik